# XOAUTH authentication on imap-mail.outlook.com and MS Graph API tokens

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, hotmail

Currently we get access/refresh tokens using MS Live API (https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf). Then we authenticate to imap-mail.outlook.com using this access token:

```
auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (email, access_token)
imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
imap_conn.debug = 4
imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
imap_conn.select('INBOX')
print(imap_conn.list())
```

Everything works fine.

Unfortunately MS Live API will be deprecated soon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/migrating-from-live-sdk?view=odsp-graph-online

So we are trying to use MS Graph API tokens. We get tokens:

```
{ 'access_token': '****',
  'scope': 'User.Read Mail.Send Mail.ReadWrite', 
  'refresh_token': '***',
  'token_type': 'Bearer',
  'ext_expires_in': 0,
  'expires_in': 3600
}
```

But when we use this token, we always get:

```
46:15.27 > b'JEKB1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2'
46:15.57 < b'+ '
46:15.57 write literal size 1584
46:21.21 < b'JEKB1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.'
46:21.21 NO response: b'AUTHENTICATE failed.'
```

So questions are:
1. Is it possible to connect to the imap-mail.outlook.com using MS Graph API tokens?
2. If no, how will this work when MS Live API will no longer be available?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to connect to the imap-mail.outlook.com using MS Graph API tokens?

No

> 2. If no, how will this work when MS Live API will
>      no longer be available?

You can use the Graph API for outlook directly([official docs for python](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/python),  [official docs for outlook](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/outlook-calendar-concept-overview) ,[github sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Python) ), no need to use your current way.